# label rows and columns of a sparse Matrix R

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am trying to "label" the rows and columns of a dGC Matrix in R. I am getting inputs B (a matrix) and two lists "columns" and "rows". A representative minimal example is:

```
library(Matrix)
B = matrix(c(0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0), nrow=2,  ncol=3) 
columns =c("c1","c2","c3")
rows = c("row1","row2")
as(B, "dgCMatrix")
```

I would like to "label" the rows and columns of my dGC Matrix. In particular consider the following package:

```
install.packages("textir")
library("textir")
data(we8there)
View(we8thereCounts)
```

My matrix should be like the "we8thereCounts" dgC Matrix provided as sample data in the "textir" package (intellectual credit to Matt Taddy of course).

It seems most textual analysis packages for R automatically create these matrices (properly labeled), but I unfortunately inhert the data in this "raw" format. Can anyone point me to helpful commands?

Thanks in advance!

Edited: the number of columns to match my request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dimnames<-` to set the names.  But note that the number of values in the column and rows names must match the number of columns and rows in the Matrix.  In your example, you created a matrix with `nrow=3,  ncol=2` but then you have a `columns` vector of length 3 and a `rows` one of length 2.

Here's an example that works

```
B = matrix(c(0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0), nrow=2,  ncol=3) 
columns =c("c1","c2","c3")
rows = c("row1","row2")
Bs = as(B, "dgCMatrix") 
dimnames(Bs) = list(rows,columns)

# 2 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#      c1 c2 c3
# row1  .  .  .
# row2  4  1  .
```

Comment: perfect thanks very much. I edited the matrix dimensions as you pointed out they dont add up.